# Angular model variable updating too early before DOM updates, causing UI to be "behind"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom, angularjs-digest

I'm trying to build an Angular Tag Directive that functions not too dissimilarity from Stack Overflow's Tag input form. It uses a div with a border to create the illusion of a form, and then a div containing a list of tags to the left of an input field where you can type:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tag-wrapper">
        <div class="tags" ng-repeat="tag in selectedTags">
            <div>
                [[ tag.name ]]
                <span class="remove" ng-click="removeTag(tag)"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="tag-input"
           ng-model="tagInput"
           ng-style="{ width: inputLength + 'px'}"
           ng-keypress="tagInputKeyPress($event)"
           ng-keyup="updateSuggestionList()"
           ng-focus="toggleSuggestionVisibility()"
           ng-blur="toggleSuggestionVisibility()" />
</div>
```

Please note I'm using `[[]]` as my interpolation provider for Angular because I have another templating engine already using `{{}}`.

When a key is pressed in the input, it runs a function to check if the key is a backspace or enter or a space to create/remove a tag:

```
$scope.tagInputKeyPress = function(event) {
    // Currently using jQuery.event.which to detect keypresses, keyCode is deprecated, use KeyboardEvent.key eventually:
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

    // event.key == ' ' || event.key == 'Enter'
    if (event.which == 32 || event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Remove any rulebreaking chars
        var tag = $scope.tagInput;
        tag = tag.replace(/["']/g, "");
        // Remove whitespace if present
        tag = tag.trim();

        $scope.createTag(tag);

    // event.key == 'Backspace'
    } else if (event.which == 8 && $scope.tagInput == "") {
        event.preventDefault();

        // grab the last tag to be inserted (if any) and put it back in the input
        if ($scope.selectedTags.length > 0) {
            $scope.tagInput = $scope.selectedTags.pop().name;
        }
    }
    $scope.inputLength = $(element).find('input.tag-input').parent().innerWidth() - $(element).find('.tag-wrapper').outerWidth() - 1;

    return true;
};
```

The bit I'm having problems with is the last line before the return statement. **What it is meant to do** is recompute the width of the `.tag-wrapper` element and adjust the width of the `input` element to suit via this `ng-style` property:

```
ng-style="{ width: inputLength + 'px'}"
```

However, as it currently stands, the input length is always one step behind the UI, causing the input to overflow. This is because:

1. It firstly adds a new tag onto the `selectedTags` list.
2. It computes the width of `.tag-wrapper`.
3. It returns true letting the original key event pass through
4. Angular's digest cycle runs and appends a new tag into the DOM. **The width of `.tag-wrapper` is now bigger, and the `input` overflows.**

Here is an example of this:

[image]

Right now, step 4 is happening after step 2. **I need step 2 to happen after step 4**.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modify your createTag method to have a callback, and set the inputLength within the callback.

Alternative hack: wrap the setting of inputLength within a $timeout, to force the the line to be executed in the following digest call.

Comment: Can't seem to get the callback to fix this problem. It actually just causes the input to be even more behind. Can you give me an example?

Also, the timeout idea, while clever, causes flickering which is not ideal.

Comment: Ended up going with a timeout of 0 milliseconds and setting an `overflow:hidden;` on the containing element.